# View current set of guard nodes of a certain client

Tags: guard-node

How can I view the currently selected guards of my Tor browser (not just the one in action, but all three, my client keeps in a list)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your operating system, but on Linux go to `tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor` and open the file named `state`. Here you'll see the sampled guards. Also note the `confirmed_idx` field, which states the position of the guard in the confirmed list. Right now Tor uses one guard for circuits, and three directory guards (the other guards will not have `confirmed_idx` fields).

**Edit:** I don't think this answer is completely accurate. This is where Tor stores its guards, but I'm not sure I'm interpreting the state file correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I found the file, but I've got 4 nodes with confirmed_idx fields from 0 to 3. Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

You only get one guard node. After the guard node you traffic goes to the middle node and then to the exit node.

Click here to see them:

[image]